# How to use email validation inside a custom validation function?

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a custom validation function. Now I want to validate email inside that function, how can I do that?
Below is my code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'validateEmail'],
    ];
}

public function validateEmail($attribute, $params) {
    if(ctype_digit($this->email)){
        if(strlen($this->email)!=10)
            $this->addError($attribute,'Phone number should be of 10 digits');
    else{// Email validation using emailvalidator.}
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use `email` validator.

Comment: Yes, but i want to use it inside a custom validation function as you can see inside the else statement.
I want the same email field to validate for email or else phone number.

Comment: expression for email validation `'/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/`

Comment: Thanks, this might help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the [email validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-emailvalidator.html) directly. The `message` is the error message that will be added to the model when [`validateAttribute`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#validateAttribute%28%29-detail) is used. If you want to use the default error message you can leave it out:

```
public function validateEmail($attribute, $params) {
    ...
    else {
        $emailValidator = new \yii\validators\EmailValidator();
        $emailValidator->message = "Invalid Email";
        $emailValidator->validateAttribute($this, $attribute));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same thing, but guess what, no matter what email i choose it always enters in the if statement. Like:
        else{
            if (!$validator->validate($attribute, $params)) 
                $this->addError($attribute,'Invalid email!'); 
        }

Result: "Invalid email" always.

Comment: Also, the way you are passing the params is wrong i guess, it should be :
 if (!$emailValidator->validateAttribute($attribute, $params))

Comment: Hmm. The [API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#validateAttribute%28%29-detail) suggests `($model, $attribute)` as the parameters.

Comment: If i am passing the values by the way you are suggesting `($model, $attribute)`, its giving me the error:

`PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Object of class frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm could not be converted to string`

Comment: And when i am doing it like : `($attribute, $params)` It is always validating the string even if the format of an email is correct though.

Comment: Is the line `$validator = new \yii\validators\EmailValidator();` in your code?

Comment: yes it is. Actually let me show you the code my custom validator:

`public function validateEmail($attribute, $params) {
        $validator = new \yii\validators\EmailValidator();
        if(ctype_digit($this->email)){
            if(strlen($this->email)!=10)
                $this->addError($attribute,'Phone number should be of 10 digits');
        }
        else{
            if (!$validator->validate($this, $attribute)) 
                $this->addError($attribute,'Invalid email!'); 
        }
    }`

Comment: The line `$validator->validate($this, $attribute)` should be `$validator->validate($this, $attribute)`

Comment: I tried that it is returning an error
`PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Object of class frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm could not be converted to string`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109319/discussion-between-topher-and-shubham-dixit).